# Publish date without milliseconds

Tags: youtube-data-api

Some days ago the service "channel.lists" is returning dates without milliseconds.

Ex: it's expected "2008-06-19T15:20:55.000Z" but service return "2008-06-19T15:20:55Z"

Then this throw an exception on my process.

gratts

Comment: Please, specify what platform you are using to send the request

Comment: Open a bug report on Google's own [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues) and link back that here on this thread (for others to follow it).

Comment: We are sending the request on Python with Youtube Library. I Opened the ticket https://issuetracker.google.com/156243270.
Thank you!